# Spivak: Are these two proposed solutions to $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}\sin{(n^n)}}{n+1}$ technically correct?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

In Ch. 20 of Spivak's *Calculus* we are tasked with finding the limit

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}\sin{(n^n)}}{n+1}$$

The easiest way to do it (which I saw in the solution manual after my more prolix attempts which I show below) is

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}\sin{(n^n)}}{n+1}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{(-1)^n\sin{(n^n)}}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot\frac{n}{n+1}=0\cdot 1=0$$

I'd like to confirm if either of the two methods below are technically correct

**Solution 1**

$$0\leq \left | \frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}\sin{(n^n)}}{n+1} \right |=\left | \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1}\sin{(n^n)} \right | \leq\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1}$$

$$0\leq \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left | \frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}\sin{(n^n)}}{n+1} \right |=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left | \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1}\sin{(n^n)} \right | \leq\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1}=0$$

I'd like to conclude now that

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}\sin{(n^n)}}{n+1}=0$$

But it seems I've obtained

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left |\frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}\sin{(n^n)}}{n+1}\right |=0$$

**Solution 2**

Obviously there are simpler ways to solve the problem than below, but I am trying to make sure that this argument based on two cases is technically correct.

If $n$ is odd then

$$\frac{-\sqrt{n}}{n+1}\leq\frac{-\sqrt{n}\sin{(n^n)}}{n+1}\leq \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1}$$

Thus

$$0\leq \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{-\sqrt{n}\sin{(n^n)}}{n+1}\leq 0$$

If $n$ is even then

$$\frac{-\sqrt{n}}{n+1}\leq\frac{\sqrt{n}\sin{(n^n)}}{n+1}\leq \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1}$$

Thus

$$0\leq \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{-\sqrt{n}\sin{(n^n)}}{n+1}\leq 0$$

Therefore, we have shown that

$$\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists N\ \forall n, n\in\mathbb{N}\land n>N\implies \left | \frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}\sin{(n^n)}}{n+1} \right |<\epsilon$$

Hence

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}\sin{(n^n)}}{n+1}$$

**Question:** are solutions $1$ and $2$ technically correct?

Comment: Also, ${\sqrt{n} \over n+1} \le {\sqrt{n} \over n} \le \sqrt{1 \over n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both solutions are correct.

For solution 1, you can finish by using the fact that $|x| \to 0$ and $x \to 0$ are equivalent conditions. This is because $|x - 0| \leq \varepsilon$ is the same thing as $||x| - 0| \leq \varepsilon$ (both left-hand sides simplify to $|x|$).

For solution 2, you are also correct, although there is no need to separate into cases; you can just use the squeeze theorem directly (like you noted).